# Best approach to generate a bunch of graphs from BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a ~10GB table in BigQuery which holds about ~2000 series that I want to plot individually using Matplotlib. The table has three columns, `series_id`, `date`, and `value`. I want to generate a time series for each value, 2000 times.

I could do 2000 queries, one for each series, and generate a chart for each one, but this seems extremely inefficient. Is there a better way that also doesn't cause memory problems?

This seems interesting, but I'm not sure if it's the right direction: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator#google_cloud_bigquery_table_RowIterator_to_dataframe_iterable

Comment: From the BigQuery costs side: Please query the whole table with the right time range to another table partitioned by the `series_id`. This will cost you 10GB quota. Then query the new table for each series, 2000 times 10 MB. This will be 30GB in total versus 2000 times 10 GB, 20TB quota.